# Interactive level sets of polynomials

Tags: plotting, manipulate, polynomials, interactive

I'm new to *Mathematica* and I need some help with the following problem. I would like given some positive integer n, to have mathematica plot the level sets of a (say monic) polynomial of degree n, p(z), with roots z_j in the unit disk. The trick is that I want to be able to change the position of z_j in an interactive way (e.g dragging them around inside the unit disk or choose the roots in advance by clicking at some points in the plane and then have *Mathematica* read that input and draw the level set of the corresponding polynomial). For example, I've tried something like the following piece of code (for n=2) but it's not exactly what I need. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

```
 Manipulate[
  Show[ContourPlot[
    Abs[(x + I*y - x1 - I*y1) (x + I*y - x2 - I*y2)] == 
    Abs[(x1 + I*y1) (x2 + I*y2)], {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}]],
    {{x1, {-5, 5}}, Locator}, {{y1, {-5, 5}}, Locator},
    {{x2, {-5, 5}}, Locator}, {{y2, {-5, 5}}, Locator}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: What exactly do you need?  It seems to work in the way you describe.  Is the problem with the equation `Abs[(x + I*y - x1 - I*y1) (x + I*y - x2 - I*y2)] == Abs[(x1 + I*y1) (x2 + I*y2)]`?  You could plot the real and imaginary parts, but I don't know if that would be what you want.

Comment: For a start I can suggest this: `Manipulate[Show[ContourPlot[Abs[(x + I*y - Complex @@ x1) (x + I*y - Complex @@ x2)] == Abs[(Complex @@ x1) (Complex @@ x2)], {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}]], {{x1, {-5, 5}}, Locator}, {{x2, {-5, 5}}, Locator}]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 My problem with my code was that I did not want to have to move the points by real and imaginary part separately but rather than complex numbers on the plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate fiddly held expressions! But I managed to get this `Dynamic` construct to work.

```
n = 4;
left[x_, y_, z__] := Abs@Product[x + I y - Complex @@ zz, {zz, {z}}]
right[z__] := Abs@Product[Complex @@ zz, {zz, {z}}]
DynamicModule[{z = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {n, 2}]},
 Dynamic[Show[
   ContourPlot[
    left[x, y, Sequence @@ z] == right[Sequence @@ z],
     {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, ImageSize -> Large], 
   Graphics[
    Evaluate@Table[With[{i = i}, Locator[Dynamic[z[[i]]]]], {i, n}] 
   ]]]
 ]
```

[image: Dynamic levels]

I'm not sure of the best way to limit the locators to within the unit circle... in fact I hardly understand my own code :-)

But at least you now have an easy way to set up an arbitrary number of poles.

**Update**

On Mathematica v8 dragging one locator drags them all together. Don't know why. The requested feature in the comments requires the following replacement: change the `Graphics[...]` to

```
Graphics[(Evaluate@
          Table[With[{i = i}, Line[{{0, 0}, z[[i]]}]], {i, n}])~Join~
         (Evaluate@
          Table[With[{i = i}, Locator[Dynamic[z[[i]]]]], {i, n}])
]
```

Works as normal on my machine with M.v.10

[image: Lines]

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Question: Is it easy to modify this code in order to have the segments joining each point to {0,0} show in the picture ?

Comment: Yes. Immediately after `Graphics[` insert `Line[{{0, 0}, #}] & /@ z,` I can't do any rigorous testing right now, as it seems, my code doesn't work on Mathematica v8 (I wrote it using v10).

Comment: Thanks. It seems that I'm not able to move the points in the picture anymore though.

Comment: Yeah, I've got a similar issue on v8. I'll look into it tomorrow.